# Questions about equipment for personal use, when on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question of mine, [about a cheap replacement for a fascia roll](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/868/what-is-a-cheap-replacement-to-a-fascia-roll), was closed, apparantly "because it is about how to build your own equipment." I'm sure the closer will eloborate.

I'd argue that questions of the type "what can I use for " or "what properties does a proper  have" are on topic. We don't always have a specialist on hand to ask wether the knee brace we bought is good or not, or what to look out for when buying a flexibar or whatever.

To be clear, questions about actually building stuff I don't see on-topic here. But the properties or specs to which one builds yes. So if we were talking about surgical equipment, the question "what maximum surface roughness is tolerable in surgical steel" would bo on topic, then the poster would have to ask a machinist on how to achieve this roughness.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see "What other object has about the same diameter and hardness" as a health question either. Maybe better on DIY?

Comment: To answer the question you have to have used or handled a roll. I see no other way (except lab testing for hardness, but come on). Why DIY, why do you think they are better equipped to answer?

Comment: "What maximum surface roughness is tolerable in surgical steel" is not a health related question either, imo. Why DIY? Because on DIY is about DYI, which is what you what to do, I presume. Just a suggestion. I don't think you'll get the answer you want here; trying to help you find a site where you might have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an on-topic question about equipment use:

> My daughter has been diagnosed as having scoliosis (Thoraco-Lumbo-Sacral-Orthosis) and has been prescribed a Boston Brace, which has to be worn 23 hours/day.
>
> I have seen some parents discussing the Charleston Bending Brace (also called a "nighttime" brace because it is only worn while sleeping.) Does anyone have experience with the night time brace? I've read in some places that it's as efffective as a Boston Brace.

An example of an Off Topic equipment question:

> My daughter has been diagnosed as having scoliosis (Thoraco-Lumbo-Sacral-Orthosis) and has been prescribed a Boston Brace, which has to be worn 23 hours/day.
>
> However, it's only a molded plastic brace with 3 velcro straps.
>
> Is there a plastic polymer that anyone here knows about that I can construct my own brace out of? If you can give me advice about how to attach the velcro straps securely, that would be appreciated as well.

The second question isn't so much about health as it is about jury-rigging a prosthetic from scratch. It really isn't appropriate on this site to find a way to build a brace fro scratch which may not be appropriate in any case.

I hope this helps.